# applyBindingsToNode with observable

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, knockout.js

I have the following code:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.disablingOption = { 
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) { 
        alert(valueAccessor()); 
    }, 
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) { 
        alert(valueAccessor()); 
    } 
}; 

// Some other code 
var option = $(element); 
var tempObserver = ko.observable(true); 
ko.applyBindingsToNode(option, { 
    disablingOption : tempObserver 
 }); 
 tempObserver(false); 
//
```

My intention is to see three alert boxes, the first two saying "true" 
and the third saying "false", however I never get the third box. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `valueAccessor()` will only give you `tempObserver` back.  In order to create a dependency, you actually need to access the value of `tempObserver`.

A safe way to do this is by calling `ko.utils.unwrapObservable` on it like:

```
alert(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()));
```

`ko.utils.unwrapObservable` will properly handle returning the value for an observable or a non-observable.

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/C7Gt5/